# Can connect between hyperledger composer and Android app?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I created a network on hyperledger composer on one physical machine and create cards for admin and user
I have some questions:

1) how can I access the same network using 2 different machines(laptops) ?

2) and if it possible to connect this network on hyperledger composer to Android app ?

I want to know if these possible or not and how can do that?

And I want to know if using hyperledger fabric will be best or go on hyperledger composer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with "access the network":

- If you mean sending queries to it, one possible solution could be to
  launch the composer REST server, open ports, and you should be good
  to go.
- If you mean accessing the composer backend, just opening ports should be enough.

To "connect" the network with an Android app I suppose you mean sending queries to it, so the REST server solution should work.

About the last question, it also depends on what are you using the tools for. If you are learning or doing fast PoCs, Composer is a good election (even when IBM said on october 2018 they wouldn't continue development), but for serious or production work i'd go directly with Fabric.

**Update: composer-rest-server**

You can use `composer-rest-server` to connect to your composer network from different machines and send transactions to it. Just have to launch it in the machine you have composer running, like so:

```
composer-rest-server
```

By default it launches a web service on port 3000, so you can direct your browser to `http://localhost:3000/explorer/` to interact with it from the same machine. To connect from a different machine, if you are in the same network, just point the other machine to the local IP of the composer machine, on port 3000. Let's say the composer machine has private IP 192.168.0.10, then you would have to point the browser of the other machine to `http://192.168.0.10:3000/explorer/`. If you are in different networks you would need to open router ports, redirect them to the composer machine, and connect to its public IP instead of its private IP. More information about composer-rest-server: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/integrating/getting-started-rest-api

Comment: I mean with (access the network) : I can make transactions in the same network on hyperledger composer using 2 different laptops. Is it possible? If yes, can you give me some details please.

Comment: Thanks, it help a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider marking it as a valid answer.

Comment: If you please, I want to ask another question. Now  I mean with Android app as client Android app ,so I want to do user interface for user to register (as new participate) -> in this case I want to create a new identify card for this user or he can log in to the network so I want to check his password . Now  my question is how can do this  ?

Comment: So I don't need the interface as present in rest server  I need client app

Comment: You can do http calls to the rest server from your application and interact with your blockchain this way. Anyway, if you are trying to do a production ready development, you should consider migrating to pure Fabric, because Composer is a tool for fastly getting an idea of how your network should be, but it is not a tool to run a production network.